# Rewrite Subdirectory to URL String with Episerver Platform

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdirectory, episerver

I need to create a rule that will change a subdirectory to part of the url string by replacing the "/" with "-". The product id number was added to the end of all URLs to avoid having duplicate URLs, but it should not be in its own folder. The platform is Episerver. Here is an example:

```
www.example.com/products/blue-toy/2324

www.example.com/products/hair-spray/3374
```

to

```
www.example.com/products/blue-toy-2324

www.example.com/products/hair-spray-3374
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as your very first rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(products)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /$1/$2-$3 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Based on the updated URL... would this be correct? ^(/products/) /$1-$2 [L,NC,R=302]

Answer (score 0):

If using EPiServer, a .NET CMS, a working way is to take anubhavas rewrite rule and import it into the Rewrite Module in IIS.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules

After first installing it of course.